# Preloading fonts size example

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, preload

I was reading about the preloading mechanism and I came across with this article [preload](https://alligator.io/html/preload-prefetch/). It has an example here https://jsfiddle.net/Alligatorio/b76aagnw/ and explains that the part

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log('Loaded')
}
```

It's executed before the fonts been fetched.

**I use chrome latest version and I don't see this effect. I only see message loaded after the fonts been fetched**

**Note. This happens only when i ran this example using react create app**

Am I missing something or didn't I understand what he meant? I really want to know how this works.